# Finding author and source of quote about holocaust

Tags: quote-source

I cannot remember where I read a quote about holocaust (partial quote further down) and although I'm almost certain that it was from some jewish author who himself survived holocaust I cannot remember the author either.

The quote itself was along the lines of:

> ...because it was not the devil that made holocaust, but you and I.
>   Where there is humanity, there is holocaust/Auschwitz.

I also think the context was that labelling the holocaust and people who did it as simply evil was a disservice to the cause.

Can anyone recognize the quote or maybe the style and sentiment of writing?

Comment: [Some of these](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/4187.Primo_Levi) seem vaguely similar.

Comment: @TomasBy I surveyed some of his works and although I cannot find the quote or decide if it was him I think that it hemped me remember that the original quote was mentioning Auschwitz specifically, so maybe that will narrow it down a little.